# HTML CSS JS, Adding a class in java-script doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know people already asked this but really I searched and searched and did not find anything that can help me.
So I have built a small game you probably heard of: 7 BOOM. It's a small class assignment and I have a problem with adding classes in JavaScript but without using jQuery as we did not get so far yet in school.

All I want to do is that on a given click with some if conditions a `div` will size down a bit and then size bigger like a pop animation. When I add the class with the animation directly into the HTML page inside the div using `class="animeclass"` it works perfectly but when I add it to the element in Javascript using `classList.add("animeclass");` nothing happens. I kinda confused but it.
any help would be much appreciated. here is some code:
the HTML

```
<div id="infoi">
    <div id="scoreButton787">
         <h1 id="scoreText787">0</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

the CSS

```
.animateScalePop{
  animation: animScaleDown 1000ms 1;
}
@keyframes animScaleDown{
0%{transform: scale(1.0);}
15%{transform: scale(0.787);}
75%{transform: scale(1.6787);}
100%{transform: scale(1.0);}
}
```

the JS

```
 function startScalingPop(element){

    element.classList.add("animateScalePop");
}
```

i wont post the entire code cause there are alot of stuff here but i promise you when the time comes it goes into the startScalingPop(element) function 100 percent it just dosent work. the element gets the correct element from the html page.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you're actually using the function `startScalingPop`. The function should work imho.

Comment: I can see it working if you selected right element and have called the function https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMMbrv Animation appears strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post working examples via comment so I added an answer. So here's an example of basically on button click, we add the `animateScalePop` class to `#infoi`. It seems to animate in this scenario so I think the code you posted seems to be correct.

What may not be correct however is the animation itself, but that sounds like part of the assignment for you to figure out. Overall though, what you've posted here seems to be correct and working! Feel free to comment and ask questions but overall I think you're heading on the right track!

```js
function startScalingPop(element){

    element.classList.add("animateScalePop");
}

function scaleSomething() {
  var infoi = document.getElementById("infoi");
  startScalingPop(infoi);
}
```

```css
.animateScalePop{
  animation: animScaleDown 1000ms 1;
}
@keyframes animScaleDown{
0%{transform: scale(1.0);}
15%{transform: scale(0.787);}
75%{transform: scale(1.6787);}
100%{transform: scale(1.0);}
}
```

```html
<div id="infoi">
    <div id="scoreButton787">
         <h1 id="scoreText787">0</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<button onClick="scaleSomething()">Scale this</button>
```

Comment: ok well, thank you first of all to all of you.
if I add a class with javascript should it be seen in the dev console on chrome? cause maybe it doesn't even add it... for some reason...i'll add an alert on the function lets see if even get an alert...

Comment: Yep, the alert is there but no change to element no animation at all...

Comment: Are you saying in the example I created you aren't seeing any amination when you click `Scale this`? Also, after clicking the button you should see the new class through Chrome Dev console.

Comment: yeah, I saw it thank you, the problem was that I was removing the class too quick had to put a little delay to it like I have added the delay it just didn't work... got it working, thank you.

Comment: btw if you want to see it in action :)